# SharedPreferences not able to set

Tags: java, android

Whats wrong with the below code

I am not able to retrieve a simple setting saved in SharedPreferences. s1 is always "". What it the small mistake I am doing >
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MyTestPref", 0);

```
    String s = "Item1";
    sp.edit().putString("VAL", (s));
    sp.edit().apply(); //also tried commit
    String s1 = (sp.getString("VAL", ""));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
String s = "Item1";
sp.edit().putString("VAL", (s));
sp.edit().commit(); //also tried commit
String s1 = (sp.getString("VAL", ""));
```

use `commit()` not `apply()`.

EDIT:

```
final String PREFERENCE_NAME = "your_pref";
String s = "Item1";
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("VAL", s);
editor.commit();

String s1 = preferences.getString("VAL", "");
```

[image]

Comment: yes, I think sp.edit().commit() and sp.edit().putstring() pair is not working, while editor.putString and commit is working. Dont know why ? ideally both are referring to same object ?

Comment: See my screenshot above, I'm using the code I above. It should work. Also, sp.edit().putString() does work.

Comment: I did a small experiment. I modified s. and added the code   String s = "ItemXX";
  preferences.edit().putString("VAL", (s));
  editor.commit();
  String s1 = (sp.getString("VAL", "")); Now s1 is reading old value...

Comment: Putting s inside parentheses does not work. So just use, putString("VAL", s) instead of putString("VAL", (s)).

Comment: @jekkusan Putting parentheses around parameters does not harm them: http://ideone.com/RxoSKZ

Comment: @Manish Every time you call `edit()`, a new `Editor` is created. So, calling it twice will mean you've created two new objects. That's why `Editor editor = sp.edit()` is correct.

Comment: I'm not really sure about that parentheses thing. Setting the string to another variable with these parentheses is ok. I'm just wondering why it doesn't work with SharedPref.

Comment: @jekkusan Because of my second comment there; as he was calling `edit().putString()` then `editor.commit()`, the committed `Editor` was not the same as the one which had the string.